# Detect movements of a person?

Tags: sensors

I'm working on a Virtual Reality game. I want to detect the position or movement of most of the bones in the human body(e.g. Knees, elbows, shoulders, hands and legs). This person may wear special equipment. How should I detect this?? I also want to get the distances between a certain position(e.g. The Arduino board) and each bone. Any ideas?

Comment: google for "arduino kinect" and you will get lots of ideas.

Comment: I'm sorry but saying you want to do *some massively complex project* and then asking for "any ideas" does not fit into the question-and-answer format of this site. Please narrow your question down somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called motion capture. If you google it, you'll find a Wikipedia article that can give you a starting point for deciding which of the many available techniques will suit your project. Youtube also has several videos explaining motion capture, and different technologies.

Comment: The problem is that the player is not going to be visible

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: The player is going to be in a giant hamster ball, and he wouldn't be visible, so I need to use some kind of suit.

Comment: Bigger problem is that we are not a design bureau.  If we were, I doubt we would use Arduino for this in the first place.